# How to compare group of columns to another group of columns in Excel and highlight matches?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have two groups of data. Each group is 3 columns. Group 1 is 1500 cells long. Group 2 is 500 cells long.

I need to see if there are any matches from group 2 in group 1 and highlight them.

I know you are able to do this with two columns in excel using conditional formatting. But how do I do this when there are 3 associated columns vs. another 3 associated columns?

Comment: Could you share portion of data as screen shot and write what you want to match between columns !!

Comment: Hi Rajesh, unfortunetly the data is confidential so i cant share it. But the basic setup up is  Name (column 1) Hospital (column 2) Id (column 3). The headers are the same for the second group. I want to see if any of group 2 matches with group 1. So Name+Hospital+id

Comment: I Did need to mention that there is mostly text here and not numbers. I considered conconocating the 3 columns then using countif, but it wasnt an exact match

Comment: Can anyone help here?

Comment: I'd suggest creating some dummy data - keep the structure of your sheet intact and just throw in some made up names and numbers. Take out any identifying information so you're not sharing anything confidential. That way we can understand how your sheet is laid out and answer your question.

Comment: @NajiSalem,, check I've posted solution will help you ! ☺

Answer (score -1):

**To Compare two Group of records to highlight duplicates in group particular you need to follow these steps.**

*In the below show example the method compare record from Group 2 with Group 1 and highlights duplicate records in Group 1.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Select data range `A30:C35`.
- From **Home Tab** click **Conditional Formatting.**
- Click **New Rule** & select category **Use formula to determine which Cells to Format.**
- Write this Formula:

`=COUNTIFS($A$30:$A$35,$F30,$B$30:$B$35,$G30,$C$30:$C$35,$H30)`

- Click **Format** button, apply appropriate color & finish with **OK.**

**N.B.** *Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: Write your concern why this post has been down voted, help me to improvise it,, since the suggested method is fully functional and for better understanding I've attached Screen Shot also. !!